# How to delete cached HSTS policies for all domains and websites in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, hsts

I know I can go in `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and delete cached `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` for specific domains but I don't even know which domains have been added to that cache/database.

Is there a way to clear the cached HSTS policies for ALL domains and start from scratch?

I'd prefer to not have to reset all Chrome settings, if possible. Just HSTS. The reason being I started using NextDNS and instead of seeing their nicely formatted block/allow page , I get a warning about invalid certificates and it takes me a moment to evaluate what is really happening.

I know this may sound awful but I’m fine with temporarily being open to TLS hijack attacks while Chrome works on caching new HSTS policies as I visit the websites.